# I can't convert json object to JS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to convert responseJson.result (JSON Object) to data (JS Object).
When I use console log or alert it's return undefined.

I don't know what's wrong  - something about console log or alert method or stringify?

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    data: null,
  };
}

componentWillMount() {
  return fetch("www.abc.xyz/api")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      let ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
      });

      this.setState({
        data: JSON.stringify(responseJson.result),
      }, function() {
      });

      var resultJ = this.state.data.result;
      alert(resultJ);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert("0 : Recrods On This Module ")
    });
}
```

Comment: what does `console.log(responseJson)` before you `setState`say?

Comment: datasource from responseJson it's work on listview.
but I want to  convert responseJson  to data and set data on Listview

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` call is asynchronous which means the state values are not available immediately. You already have the callback parameter in your `setState` set. You only need to use it e.g.

```
this.setState({
    data: JSON.stringify(responseJson.result),
}, function () {
    var resultJ = this.state.data.result;
    alert(resultJ);
});
```

Comment: after try this. it's return undefined :( why not work